# Affiliate software to attract incoming customers

Tags: looking-for-a-script, affiliate

I am close to starting a new website for a small business which imports products from USA to Australia.  The wholesaler says he will allow my client to be the sole distributor for Australia & New Zealand.

I'm not sure what CMS or shopping cart software to use yet, but it will need to include an affiliate system to allow advertisers to push customers our way.

Do you have any suggestions for robust, flexible affiliate software?

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate your website with the API from http://zferral.com/ which has plenty of Affiliate options.

CS-Cart Shopping cart also has a built in affiliate management system. This is a good solution over Google Affiliate which is a few hundred a month in network fees. CJ.com is also a good option once you're doing $50k monthly and have been online for a year.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with it myself, but I have heard good things about Post Affiliate Pro. http://www.qualityunit.com/postaffiliatepro/

It allows you to integrate with shopping cart systems such as zencart.

The downside is that it is kind of expensive, since you would need the version that integrates with the shopping cart.

If money is an issue, there is Omnistar: http://www.osiaffiliate.com/shopping-cart-affiliate-software.htm

It's cheaper, but I've heard that it is a nightmare if you want to make any changes to the it. If you can, I'd go with Post Affiliate Pro integrated with the shopping cart of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I bought [iDevAffiliate Platinum](http://www.idevaffiliate.com) (USD300). The product itself is ok, and that's a pity, because the hard work that has been put into the product is rendered useless by their horrendous support. By far the worst tech support I've encountered in my life. I cannot recommend it.

I'm currently looking for other options, if possible open source. ¿Any recommendations?

Comment: Give [elitius](http://www.elitius.com/) a shot. I haven't tried it myself, since I have no need for such software at the moment, but it's open source. If you do try it out, please let us know if it's any good.